# Is there a frontend component building tool that can be used across frameworks and versions?

Tags: frontend, web-frontend, micro-frontend, building, front-end-optimization

Is there a frontend component building tool that can be used across frameworks and versions? This tool enables front-end developers to develop any component without worrying about whether they are using Vue 2.x, Vue 3.x, or React.

Write once, run anywhere！Make components agnostic to the underlying technology stack!